# Changing to next scene after an animation ends. cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

```
-(void)test:(CCMenuItemSprite*)item
{
    [item runAction:action];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];
}
```

how do i make it so that item completes the action before the scene gets replaced?
Thanks

Comment: create a sequence action with a runBlock or callFunc action at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
CCScene* sceneToRun = ...;
CCMenuItemSprite* item = ...;
id action = ...;

id changeSceneAction = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];
}];

id seqAction = [CCSequence actions:action, changeSceneAction, nil];

[item runAction:seqAction];
```

Assume the ... represents the creation of the item. If you are using cocos2d 3.0 you would do something like:

```
id changeSceneAction = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];
}];

id seqAction = [CCActionSequence actions:action, changeSceneAction, nil];

[item runAction:seqAction];
```

Hope this helps.